# How can I send a file along the headers of a POST call, while having regular data in the request body

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, http-post

I had an existing POST API which was used to sent an object to server. Now I want to attach a file to the header of the same file. Is it possible to do such a thing. Can a request have multiple content-type.

I tried using ngFileUpload directive, and provide my object to data field of Upload.upload method. However, by doing this the entire data object seems to go in header and the request fails.

Any suggestions for sending file in headers and JSON in request body of a POST call??

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out that a HTTP request can have a single Content-type. This is as per the standards. However it is still possible and quite easy to send data along with a file using the `FormData` Object. The support for `FormData` though is not across all the versions of various browsers.